# How to print Typescript data/object on screen

Tags: html, typescript

i just want to print some data on the screen, and not on the log like console.log.

For example with Java you can print data/objects on the screen with System.out.println(Object); and you will see the object/data on the screen. How is something like this possible with Typescript and maybe using HTML?

Comment: TypeScript is basicaly a JavaScript with type system put on top of it. In Java, if i remmeber correctly, `System.out.println` would print data in a terminal. Its the same as `console.log`. Now if you wish to display data in HTML you can simply use a `.map`. If you have an array of strings then simply do `arr.map(item => <div>item</div> )` to print them in HTML. You should do some research on `.map` and JavaScript in general when working with such tasks.

Comment: In javascript there is no such thing as just "print data on screen", because it's not quite clear what screen is. The actual page is written in HTML, so you need to create an HTML element using DOM, insert text content in it, then insert this element into the page. Something like `const e = document.createElement('pre'); e.innerHTML = 'My text'; document.appendElement(e)`. There is a simpler way like `document.write('My text')` which will just insert a text node in DOM. The point is find some info on DOM APIs which let you interact with HTML page. The answer from @Lith assumes you use react